# Checking for changes in struct

Tags: c++, struct, arduino

I am working on a library (for my own use) that syncs a struct across multiple controllers via i2c, seamlessly. I got most of it working well but I'd like to check if a change have been made to the struct so I can start synchronization when that happens.

To be able to send the data over serial(i2c) I convert it to a char array.

```
struct MyStruct {
  int a = 123;
  long b = 4567890;
  String c = "abc";
};

MyStruct myData;
char bufferP[sizeof(myData)];
memcpy(bufferP, &myData, sizeof(myData));
```

And in the other end I do

```
memcpy(&myData, bufferP, sizeof(bufferP));
```

to make it back to a struct. Works great!!

I have tried to iterate through `bufferP` to check for changes so I know when to sync but it only changes if there are a difference in the number of chars in the values.

fx. if the struct is like this

```
struct MyStruct {
  int a = 123;
  long b = 4567890;
  String c = "abc";
};
```

it will output somethings like this

```
0 -> 123
1 -> 0
2 -> 82
3 -> 179
4 -> 69
5 -> 0
6 -> 143
7 -> 2
8 -> 3
9 -> 0
10 -> 3
11 -> 0
```

and if the struct like this

```
struct MyStruct {
  int a = 123;
  long b = 4567890;
  String c = "def";
};
```

it will output the exact same thing.

Can someone tell me why there are no change in the bufferP? 
When i put it back to a struct the changes are like they should bee.

And how else do i check if the struct has changed when i do not know the structure of the struct?

Comment: What type is `String`?

Comment: Isn't `String c` a pointer as in `String c = "abc";`? How does the code transmit that string's data? Here it's a string literal, so comparing a (local) pointer might work, but suppose it points to dynamic memory, whose content might change?

Comment: I'm guessing `String` isn't plain data, it contains pointers. Pointers don't serialize using the technique you used.

Comment: But why is the ´String c´ on the receiver controller then sync'd as expected?

Comment: @XerXeX "But why is the ´String c´ on the receiver controller then sync'd as expected?" Hard to tell without more info about the environment and more code showing *exactely* what you are doing. *Could be* pure luck that pointers just happen to point to memory containing what you expect but without any guarantees - there's not enough information in the question to know. You may be in Undefined Behaviour land where "what you expect" is just as valid as "crashes on the next machine you test on". Impossible to say from the information given.

Comment: That's not really a conversion, but a simple copy. Do all devices have the same architecture and ABI? If not, you are inviting trouble.

Comment: Yes alle devices have the same structure. But i guess that I should ditch the String and use char instead. Its just a pain to work with sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Serialize the string separately. This means: serialize the structure *without* the string, then serialize the length of the string, then serialize the content of the string.
2. Replace the string with a `char[50]`.  (Or whatever size suits you.)

Comment: Yes but I can't do it this way when I don't know the structure.

Comment: huh? how can you not know the structure? In any case, in your question, you most certainly know the structure.

Comment: Yes but this if for a library, so I can't know how the end user decides to build there struct, and as long as it's the same on sender and receiver this shouldn't matter.

Comment: well then, require that whoever uses your library must use self-contained data types like `char[X]` instead of `String`.